# Assign javascript array to list of JSON objects with a property name?

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

I would like to convert a javascript array which looks like:

```
['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.facebook.com']
```

to a list of JSON objects that looks like this:

```
[{"redirectUri": "https://www.google.com"},
{"redirectUri": "https://www.facebook.com"}]
```

I have tried using `Object.assign({}, array);`

however this retuns json with the parameter name as the index of the array value and are all in a single object:

```
{"0": "https://www.google.com", "1": "https://www.facebook.com"},
```

is there a way to change this to use a custom parameter name dynamically?

Comment: `array.map(redirectUri => ({ redirectUri }) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `map` your elements respectively, using **[`Array.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**:

```
let result = arr.map(o => {
  return {
    "redirectUri": o
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
let arr = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.facebook.com'];

let result = arr.map(o => {
  return {
    "redirectUri": o
  }
});
console.log(result);
```